# How to get block from controller in magento 2

Tags: magento2, blocks

I want to get block `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar`, I tried this code but it not work and show error

```
Type Error occurred when creating the object: `Vendor/Module/Block/Search`
```

My code

```
$resultPage = $this->layoutFactory->create();
$blockToolbar = $resultPage->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar');
var_dump($blockToolbar->getCurrentOrder());
exit;
```

I tried " Code phtml " in phtml file, it works

Code phtml

```
$blockToolbar = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar');
var_dump($blockToolbar->getCurrentOrder());exit;
```

**UPDATE**

I used `$objectManager` and it works

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$blockToolbar = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar');
var_dump($blockToolbar->getCurrentOrder());
exit;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call block function using below ways :

**Method 1:**

```
protected $layoutFactory;

public function __construct(
   ...
   \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutFactory $layoutFactory,
   ...
) {
   ...
   $this->layoutFactory = $layoutFactory;
   ...
}
```

Then you can instantiate a block like this:

```
$block = $this->layoutFactory->create()->createBlock('Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar');
var_dump($block->getCurrentOrder());exit;
```

**Method 2 :**

```
$block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar');    
var_dump($block->getCurrentOrder());exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should return value,
Follow below code

```
$resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
$blockToolbar = $resultPage->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar');
return $resultPage;
```